# I am looking for drivers for my Epson Stylus CX4300 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, scanner, epson

I haven't been able to find software drivers for my Epson Stylus CX4300.  This is a multi-function device consisting of a printer and scanner.

The articles on the forums refer to older versions of Ubuntu and furthermore, Avasis no longer provide drivers as suggested in the articles.

This morning I even phoned Epson in Johannesburg and they told me that my device is not compatible with Ubuntu.

How difficult is it to "translate", for example, Windows 7 drivers into what is required for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

> How difficult is it to "translate", for example, Windows 7 drivers into what is required for Ubuntu?

Difficult. Besides that you are not even allowed to look at the code since it is protected by copyright laws.

> I am looking for drivers for my Epson Stylus CX4300 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

In general this is NOT how Linux works. We have -generic- drivers. This means we have a driver that supports a range of printers (and if you printer fits in that range it is supprted though specific options might not be in that driver).

This printer works with the standard printer utility. But you might need to choose a driver for it from the printer installation menu that is close to your printer. 
It is not listed on http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/p_Supported_Printers.php but similiar printers are...

```
Printer Model   Driver Name Epson 
Stylus CX4100   escp2-cx4100 Epson 
Stylus CX4200   escp2-cx4200 Epson 
Stylus CX4400   escp2-cx4400 Epson 
Stylus CX4500   escp2-cx450
```

So install it as a CX4200 or CX4400 and it will print.

The scanner is another matter. You can use this as a guide: [How do I get an Epson Stylus DX4450 - All-In-One Printer/Scanner working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127600/how-do-i-get-an-epson-stylus-dx4450-all-in-one-printer-scanner-working)  but you need to get the printer to work 1st.